# What can a genie do?

Tags: the-sims-3

In previous games, the genie was a destructive force to be reckoned with, and asking the genie for the wrong thing could easily result in a total party kill, or your entire house burning down.

What are the wishes offered by the Showtime incarnation of the genie, and what are their effects, and possible misfires, if any?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Wikia](http://sims.wikia.com/wiki/Genie#The_Sims_3) and [SimsVIP](http://simsvip.com/?page_id=7472), the available wishes are as follow:

- **Beauty**: Your Sim will be beautified permanently, increasing his or her chance of executing romantic interactions successfully. *It cannot be wished for twice.*
- **Fortune**: Adds 100,000 Simoleons to your household funds.
- **Free The Genie**: After following a number of steps, the genie becomes a member of your household.*
- **Happiness**: Your Sim will obtain a permanent +25 moodlet. *It cannot be wished for twice.*
- **Large Family**: Your Sim will have triplets the next time he or she tries for a baby.
- **Long Life**: Your Sim's life will be extended by 30 days. *It cannot be wished for twice.*
- **Love**: You may choose a Sim from your Sim's relationship bar and have them fall in love instantly with your Sim. In addition, your Sim will obtain a +10 moodlet for 24 hours.
- **More Wishes**: You will be granted two additional wishes.
- **Resurrect Sim (or pet)**: Bring back to life any Sim or pet whose remains are on your lot. They will be added to your household.
- **World Peace**: You Sim will obtain a +25 moodlet for two whole days. *It cannot be wished for twice.*
- **World Misery**: Only available if your Sim has the Evil trait. Your Sim will obtain a +25 moodlet for two whole days. *It cannot be wished for twice.*

*Once you free a genie, it can no longer grant wishes. However, it retains certain magical abilities:

- Instantly clean a Sim.
- Instantly clean a house lot.
- Summon perfect quality food, except for Ambrosia.
- Remove an unwanted visitor.
- Ensorcel a Sim for 4 hours. (It temporarily adds a Sim to the active family. The Sim will have no autonomy. Not available for households already containing 8 Sims.)
- Release Sim from ensorcelment.

Released genies in *Showtime* have an extended lifetime. They can get married and have children. Genie offspring will not be able to grant wishes, but they have a 50% chance to have genie abilities, which will appear at the child stage.

There is not much information readily available about rates of success and failure consequences. I suggest you keep an eye on the above links for updated information, or experiment and share your results!